# what is the meaning of "#define setId(ptr, value) ((ptr)->id = (value), 0)

Tags: c, macros

When I read someone's code, I came across the unfamiliar code.
The code is as the following:

```
struct Employee {
    int id;
};
#define getId(ptr)  ((ptr)->id)
#define setId(ptr, value) ((ptr)->id = (value), 0)
```

I couldn't understand of `((ptr)->id = (value), 0)`. 
Is this macro the same as `((ptr)->id = (value)` ?

Comment: The `,` is the comma operator.

Comment: Did you switch `name` and `id` while transcribing the code? `name` is not used in the macro expansion. `id`, which is used in the macro expansion, is not one of the parameters of the macro.

Comment: seems overcomplicated.. can someone think of a scenario where this is useful?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath at macro fetishes

Comment: @bolov: l'art pour l'art? :)

Comment: thanks. I didn't know much about [Comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). And sorry for my mistypes.

Comment: Thank you all, finally I found `((ptr)->id=(value), 0` is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I couldn't understand of "((ptr)->id = (id), 0)". Is this macro the same like "((ptr)->id = (id)" ?

Assuming the macro definition is:

```
#define setId(ptr, name) ((ptr)->id = (name), 0)
```

If you have an expression

```
a = setId(ptr, name);
```

it is expanded to

```
a = ((ptr)->id = (name), 0);
```

When that expression is executed, the value of `a` is `0`, which is the value of the comma expression `((ptr)->id = (name), 0)`. The side effect of evaluating the expression is that the `id` member of the object that `ptr` points to is set to `name`.

Answer (score 1):

> I couldn't understand of `((ptr)->id = (id), 0)`. Is this macro the
>   same like `((ptr)->id = (id)` ?

The `,` is the [comma operator used in a complex return context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator#Complex_return) in a preprocessor macro.

So when you would call you macro, it would set id of the employee and then return `0` (it is just a design decision of a programmer, probably intended to just return `0` as meaning "no error").

But as other people noted in comments, the macro probably has an error in its definition, it should probably look like:

```
#define setId(ptr) ((ptr)->id = (id), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted seems erroneous:

```
#define setId(ptr, name) ((ptr)->id = (id), 0)
```

The `setId` macro should probably use the `name` argument instead of some local `id` identifier.  If `name` is an integer, it could be this:

```
#define setId(ptr, name) ((ptr)->id = (name), 0)
```

Otherwise, it could be something like this:

```
#define setId(ptr, name) ((ptr)->id = nameToId(name), 0)
```

Regarding the `, 0)` part, it is a instance of the comma operator: the macro expands to an expression that evaluates the assignment and then evaluates `0`. In case the result of `setId(ptr, name)` is used, its value will be always `0`.  A construct like this is not very readable and will likely generate warnings on some compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Those macros replace the "setter" and "getter" functions. Assuming that the "setter" is supposed to return 0 for success and -1 for failure, the functions would look like this

```
int getId( struct Employee *ptr )
{
    return( ptr->id );
}

int setId( struct Employee *ptr, int value )
{
    ptr->id = id;
    return 0;       // this setter always succeeds
}
```

Replacing the getter with a macro is straightforward. Replacing the setter is a bit trickier, since you need to "return" the correct value. That's where the comma operator is useful.

The comma operator evaluates the first expression and discards the result. It then evaluates the second expression, and the result of the second expression is used as the result of the comma operator. So the setter macro always evaluates to 0.